# ServiceNow storing and calling upon glide scripts

Tags: html, css, servicenow

I am creating a front end portal in ServiceNow that requires using g:evaluate to call on variables from different tables.

For example:

```
<g:evaluate var="jvar_user_name"> 
var gr = new GlideRecord('sys_user'); 
gr.get('sys_id', gs.getUserID()); 
gr.first_name; 
</g:evaluate>
```

Is there a way to store a bunch of these somewhere and then call upon them as needed, much like UI Scripts for JS and Style Sheets for CSS?  If so, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should be able to do this by using [UI Macros](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=UI_Macros).

You could create a UI Macro called **set_user_name_var** like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<j:jelly trim="false" xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:g="glide" xmlns:j2="null" xmlns:g2="null">
<g:evaluate var="jvar_user_name"> 
    var gr = new GlideRecord('sys_user'); 
    gr.get('sys_id', gs.getUserID()); 
    gr.first_name; 
</g:evaluate>
</j:jelly>
```

And then invoke the UI Macro any place where you can write jelly code, like so:

```
<g:set_user_name_var />
```

or alternatively:

```
<g:macro_invoke macro="set_user_name_var" />
```

And from that point on, the **jvar_user_name** jelly variable will exist and be able to be accessed.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<j:jelly trim="false" xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:g="glide" xmlns:j2="null" xmlns:g2="null">
<g:set_user_name_var />
${jvar_user_name}
</j:jelly>
```

Comment: amazing,  it works and will be super helpful going forward.  thanks!

Comment: Hi Dylan, my team is now working in a scoped application and I'm trying to replicate the above but I can't seem to get the invoke to work.  Is this any different in a scoped environment?